# Asus eee Note EA800 on Mac and other issues

Tags: macos, sync, tablet, ereader

I just got the [Asus eee Note EA800](http://www.Asus.com/Eee/Eee_Note/Eee_Note_EA800/) and I'm quite happy with it.
I still have a couple of issues that might be of interest to most users:

1. Is it possible to visualise PDF files in **landscape mode**? As the screen is quite small, sometimes the width is not sufficient to render entire lines of a PDF.
2. Sync on **Mac OS X/Linux**: there is no official support for Mac, but you can mount the **sd card** as a normal drive. Surprisingly though, when you put pdfs on the card, the eee Note doesn't find them. It only sees them when you import them through the (ugly) sync tool on Windows. The same applies on Linux. On the other hand, mp3s are detected no problem. It seems that the official tool changes the pdfs to make them visible to the reader.
3. **Additional software**: is there the possibility to install/add extra applications? The hardware is relatively powerful, so it could definitely run more programs than the basic ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. I usually start by zooming to 200%, using the 4th icon from the left (magnifying glass). This way the pdf will use the whole width of the screen in landscape mode. Then tap on the 6th icon from the left (looks like a laptop from the side, with a curved arrow). This will give you the landscape view.
2. I have moved dozens of pdf-s to the sd card without the sync software and I can read them on the Eee Note, so it definitely works - don't know why this doesn't work on your device, could be an old firmware - see below.
3. Yes there is! [Check this out](http://www.freeenote.org/pages/downloads.html).

If 1. and/or 2. don't work for you, this could be due to an old firmware. 3. should solve this too!